# what is the difference between [[False] * 3] * 3 and [[False for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]?

Tags: python

I am trying to initialize the 2D array with false values. Both instructions mentioned below are producing same results. Please help to know the difference between the two ?

**Input**

```
[[False] * 3] * 3 
[[False for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```

**Output**

```
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

Comment: Can you include your code in the post too and not just the title?

Comment: try `[id(i) for i in my_list]`

Comment: What is the question? They does the same thing, in different way

Comment: @Vinny No, they don't quite do the same thing. Try `x = [[False]*3]*3` and then `x[0][0] = True`.

Comment: @Vinny try `my_list[0][1] = True` to see whether they are the same

Comment: @Vinny Which is the best practice ?

Comment: how do you compare them ? if I write 'a=1st writing', 'b=2nd', then 'a==b' returns True.

Comment: @Aran-Fey you're right, it's a small gotcha. The first creates the same list object, the second creates a new list object.

Comment: @vinothkumar the first one creates one list object, with 3 pointers to it. Changing one item in one list affects all of them (since they are the same object). The second one creates a new list object every iteration - so I guess that's what you need.

Comment: @Vinny gotcha that's exactly what i want to know thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let' try this:

```
>>> a = [[False] * 3] * 3
>>> b = [[False for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
>>> a
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
>>> b
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

Now let's change a single value (do we?):

```
>>> a[0][0] = True
>>> a
[[True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, False]]
```

Note that `a` was changed in *three* positions.

```
>>> b[0][0] = True
>>> b
[[True, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

`b` was not.  That's the difference.

Comment: Wow ! Could you explain what is actually happening ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: I should have searched in that way thanks man !